# Rails migration for updated gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, migration, rails-engines

We have this gem that recently got a version boost which included a lot of new migrations.

What seems to be the consensus when running new migrations on apps with existing installations without having to wipe the database and start again?

At the moment our install_generator just copies in the updated migration.rb file but immediately conflicts with apps that already have the old tables.

So I'm looking for the cleanest way to handle gem updates that include new migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations inside gems are supposed to be written in a way such that while running new migrations, you don't have to delete old tables. Which gem are you using?